Vampire kills for revenge, the hunter falls in love with her
Please help me find this movie.
I've seen it about 2 years back on a DVD I borrowed from British library. The movie is colored and shouldn't be older that 2000 as far as I remember.
The rough plot is, a man visits a village and there's a castle nearby where everyone is afraid to go. A priest stays nearby the castle who is investigating the strange things happening at the castle. The man (movie lead) makes a small group and decide to visit the castle. They are met with a few accidents and casualties and seems to be some vampire activity.
A girl is at the castle and the lead falls in love with her. 
It is later shown that she is the vampire - she converts the lead to vampire and they live happily - this is where the movie ends.
From what I remember more - the castle was once owned by a rich lady and she had many servants. However the villagers spot strange activities like people go missing from the castle. They grow suspicious and start believing that the lady is a vampire and responsible for all the missing people. So one night they set fire to the castle and burn it down.
The girl that meets the lead is actually the daughter of that lady who escaped the fire and hunts the villagers as a revenge for their act.

Well I did find the name for this movie. The story is not exactly what I wrote above but very similar.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0431265/ - is the link for IMDB.
Name is Metamorphosis
